# Error on Firstload.php in ProductFilter Module

Tags: magento2, product

When my page is loading it will give me the warning that :

> Notice: Undefined index: custom_template in
>   /home/itnasass/public_html/app/code/Codazon/ProductFilter/Block/Product/FirstLoad.php
>   on line 32

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the **$data** array does not contain any key of **custom_template**. You can put a checking before getting data with that key as

```
  $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
  if(array_key_exists('custom_template',$data)){ 
      $templateFile = explode('/',$data['custom_template']); 
      $templateFile = $templateFile[count($templateFile)-1]; 
      $templatePath = str_replace($templateFile,'',$data['custom_template']); 
      $data['custom_template'] = $templatePath.'ajax'.$templateFile; 
  }
```

This will resolve the warning!

Comment: Where should i put this check ? after $data Variable ?

Comment: yes. if you put your code instead of image I can add the code in answer.

Comment: protected function _toHtml(){
  $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
 
  $templateFile = explode('/',$data['custom_template']);
  $templateFile = $templateFile[count($templateFile)-1];
  $templatePath = str_replace($templateFile,'',$data['custom_template']);
  //$data['custom_template'] = $templatePath.'ajax_'.$templateFile;

Comment: check the updated code

Comment: it will give me this error     Notice: Undefined variable: data in /home/itnasass/public_html/app/code/Codazon/ProductFilter/Block/Product/FirstLoad.php on line 33

Comment: oh my mistake i dont initialize data variable